# Unable to install internet explorer 11 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: software-installation

I am unable to install internet explorer in ubuntu 20.04.1. I googled and found out that i have to install virutal machine and install windows required version and it will be valid for 90 days. Is there any thing apart from this that we can install.

Comment: Any number of browsers are available for Ubuntu, why do you need IE11, whose supports ends Aug.21 anyway?  wine may be able to runsome version of IE, but the virtual machine may last longer than you think,  Hopefully, you don't need activeX for some IOT device, and a normal browser will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to install IE on ubuntu is to use a VM or dual boot. Wine is not recommended.
Also from my understanding you can use the unactivated windows 10 (free) from the Windows 10 media creation tool and it should have no expiration limit.
If you use the unactivated version, you will not having access to the personalization menu and cannot change custom colors, sounds, start menu and taskbar settings, or desktop background.
Also, there will be an annoying watermark on the screen.
Other than that it should work exactly the same at least for using IE.
Bear in mind that there are many better browsers, but I assume you have a niche use for IE and have no other choice.